# Unable to use mysql_upgrade:

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqldump

I updated mysql recently and found problem related to privileges and backup. When I am using **mysql_upgrade** command it says-

```
mysqlcheck: Got error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`'`  FOR UPGRADE' at line 1 when executing 'CHECK TABLE ...  FOR UPGRADE'
```

I searched this problem and found that this problem is due to use of delimeter in table_name and If I alter the name of table then this can be solved.
But I don't know how to search those table which are not ready to upgrade ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the valid characters for unquoted identifier characters are [documented here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html), you should be able to find non-confirming table names in [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html) using a [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) match, with this query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_name NOT RLIKE '^[0-9a-zA-Z$_]+$';
```